# How to extract table value from using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the Solar Longitude value from [this table](https://viewer.mars.asu.edu/viewer/themis#P=V77388006&T=2)

I am using this code to look at the structure of the table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://viewer.mars.asu.edu/viewer/themis#P=V77388006&T=2'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

However, when I look at the output and try to find the Solar Longitude it is not there. I even tried to saved the output of the code as a .txt file and got the same result. I did notice that my output is a lot shorter than the actual HTML code I see in the browser.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get not all content back with requests, cause it is served dynamically by the website, but you can use selenium to fix that.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://viewer.mars.asu.edu/viewer/themis#P=V77388006&T=2'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.close()

soup.select_one('[data-field="Solar Longitude"]').parent.nextSibling.get_text()
```

**Output**

```
30.528906°
```